# Why do toys in Toy Story absolutely want to avoid interacting with humans?

Tags: toy-story

Why do toys in Toy Story absolutely want to avoid interacting with humans? Why not interacting with them like they interact with the dog for example?

Comment: Dogs don't tell tales (just chase them ..well 'tails' anyway).

Comment: They don't want a big change in their world.

Answer (score 15):

The toys in Toy Story are portrayed as they would be in real life. In real life, toys don't move when a human is around. 
Who knows what they do when we don't look.. They might be doing their own thing (This might explain how I lost some of my toys when I was young)

Comment: And besides, when toys move around humans, we get the movie Small Soldiers.

Comment: I'm wondering how this unscientific answer has gotten a score of 7

Comment: @aminabzz Because there is nothing scientific about living toys.

Comment: @aminabzz .... what do you mean?  what is wrong with this answer?  If the toys behaved differently then this would be counter to how they are in real life ... therefore they wouldn't be like toys.  It's an 'out of universe' answer, but it's reasonable enough.  An in-universe answer may be what mateoc is looking for - but there probably isn't one.

Comment: Look at how Sid reacted to Woody and the toy “attack”. The toys know how humans would react (except very little ones that don’t know better) if they animated around them. They’re not there to scare kids, they’re there to bring joy, memories, and smiles to kids. Even demented kids like Sid.

Comment: @AstrikingJoachim So late. But let me tell you... It's true that living toys is not real. But this answer tells us it might be real. That's why I surprised to see its score number.

Answer (score 6):

Because it's a story that wants us to imagine that toys secretly come to life when nobody's looking. In other words, they want to tell the story about what what life might be like if that really happened, and maybe imagine our toys doing the same.

They couldn't do this in a world where toys moved freely about in front of the kids, it would take away from the suspension of disbelief.

I don't think a reason in-universe is ever given (it's just implied there are "rules" by Woody in the first film)

Comment: `I don't think a reason in-universe is ever given` Completely different movie, but very similar premise: in Bee Movie, the humans' first reaction to seeing a talking bee was _freaking out and trying to kill it_. Toys may have been warned by older toys to not reveal that they are alive.

Answer (score 2):

The reason that the toys in toy story don't want to interact with the human species is because they don't exactly know how the human will react. Children are normally rough with toys anyway and if a child saw one move or talk, they would probably get scared because it's out of the norm. Also, with an adult it would probably worse. Adults are more experienced in life and would know when danger approaches, plus it might be their child's toy and they could get scared for the child's safety. Another reason for the toys not wanting humans to see them move might have been so they didn't get split up because in toy story, they are all friends (well, most of the time!)

Answer (score 0):

Everyone of these answers is a little bit right, but the truth is actually a combination of them.

As Simba and Colmde said, toys don't move on their own in real life.  The entire story would change if the toys didn't have to "play dead" whenever a human was around, because that helps build some of the tension.

As G.Byatt and others said, a human seeing a toy move would probably cause some concern.  In fact, that exact concept was used to escape Sid, Andy's psycho neighbor, when all of Sid's mutant creations "come to life" and scare him into fleeing his bedroom.

The toys have a complete life away from Andy, and part of the fun of the movies is seeing this secret life.

Answer (score -2):

If an adult human sees a toy somewhere other than where it should be, the adult will probably put the toy back. Which means the toy will have to go through all that work again.  If a child sees the toy and picks it up, who knows where the toy will end up.  As a final thought, suppose you looked down and saw a toy like Woody sneaking across the floor. How would you react -- in real life?

Comment: For your "final thought" - You would react badly only if it were an unusual occurrence. If toys interacted as a normal thing, you wouldn't think anything of it at all.

Comment: The other points appear to be what would happen *if someone noticed the toys had move*. Not what would happen *if they observed them moving in real time*.